# calibrate touch screen (Raspberry PI 2 b+)

Tags: touchscreen

I have the **7 Inch TFT Touch Screen LCD Monitor For Raspberry Pi + Driver Board HDMI VGA 2AV** calibrated, but every time after the restart I have to calibrate it new.
Is there a way that he remembers it.
*(Sorry for my bad english)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to store calibration data in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf` which you got from `xinput_calibrator`.

Here, follow these steps.

1. Use `xinput_calibrator` utility.
2. copy the output, calibrator gave after calibration.
3. `sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf`
4. Paste the data
5. ctrl + x, yes to save.
6. `sudo reboot` to make it effective.

It should be done by now. :)

Hope it helps.