# Touch Screen Calibration - selected device is not a touchscreen I understand

Tags: touchscreen

I'm trying to calibrate my iiyama touch screen on my new raspberry pi 3.

I installed LIBTS for this :

```
sudo su
aptitude install libts-bin
```

Then I have to export two variables `LIBTS_FBDEVICE`and `LIBTS_TSDEVICE`.

I tried this :

```
export TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/dev/input/event1
export TSLIB_FBDEVICE=/dev/fb0
```

I found those values in the `/dev` and `/dev/input` directory, I checked multiple times to make sure they are the correct ones.

When I run `ts_calibrate` or `ts_test` , I keep receiving this error :

```
selected device is not a touchscreen I understand
```

Do you have any idea why ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using another tool :

```
xinput_calibrator
```

see answer here : [calibrate touch screen (Raspberry PI 2 b+)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33237/calibrate-touch-screen-raspberry-pi-2-b)